# Google Charts hAxis: How to prepend text in information box?

Tags: charts, google-visualization

I hope this is not a duplicate. When user clicks on a dot from chart, how can I prepend "Days: " in the information box?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using object notation in the data table,
we can provide both the value (`v:`) and the formatted value (`f:`)
of each cell.

```
{v: 12, f: 'Days: 12'}
```

and by default, the tooltip will display the formatted value.

see following working snippet...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  packages: ['corechart']
}).then(function () {
  var chart_data = [
    ['x', 'Times'],
    [0, 0],
    [2, 0],
    [4, 0],
    [6, 0],
    [8, 0],
    [10, 0],
    [{v: 12, f: 'Days: 12'}, 22],
    [14, 0],
    [16, 0],
  ];

  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(chart_data);

  var chart = new google.visualization.AreaChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
  chart.draw(data, {
    height: 400
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart_div"></div>
```

---

**EDIT**

There aren't any options to change the default tooltips.
But we can add our own custom tooltips.

first, we need to add another column to the data.
in this example. I use a data view.

```
// create view with tooltip column
var view = new google.visualization.DataView(data);
view.setColumns([0, 1, {  // <-- add column indexes for original columns
  // build custom tooltip column
  calc: function (dt, row) {
    var tooltip = '<div class="ggl-tooltip">';
    tooltip += '<div>' + dt.getColumnLabel(0) + ':&nbsp;';
    tooltip += dt.getFormattedValue(row, 0) + '</div>';
    tooltip += '<div>' + dt.getColumnLabel(1) + ':&nbsp;';
    tooltip += dt.getFormattedValue(row, 1) + '</div>';
    tooltip += '</div>';
    return tooltip;
  },
  p: {html: true},
  role: 'tooltip',
  type: 'string'
}]);
```

a couple things we need,
first, on the tooltip column, we need to specify a property for...

```
  p: {html: true},
```

in the options, we need to set...

```
tooltip: {
  isHtml: true
}
```

see following working snippet...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  packages: ['corechart']
}).then(function () {
  var chart_data = [
    ['Days', 'Times'],
    [0, 0],
    [2, 0],
    [4, 0],
    [6, 0],
    [8, 0],
    [10, 0],
    [12, 22],
    [14, 0],
    [16, 0],
  ];

  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(chart_data);

  // create view with tooltip column
  var view = new google.visualization.DataView(data);
  view.setColumns([0, 1, {  // <-- add column indexes for original columns
    // build custom tooltip column
    calc: function (dt, row) {
      var tooltip = '<div class="ggl-tooltip">';
      tooltip += '<div>' + dt.getColumnLabel(0) + ':&nbsp;';
      tooltip += dt.getFormattedValue(row, 0) + '</div>';
      tooltip += '<div>' + dt.getColumnLabel(1) + ':&nbsp;';
      tooltip += dt.getFormattedValue(row, 1) + '</div>';
      tooltip += '</div>';
      return tooltip;
    },
    p: {html: true},
    role: 'tooltip',
    type: 'string'
  }]);

  var chart = new google.visualization.AreaChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
  chart.draw(view.toDataTable(), {
    height: 400,
    tooltip: {
      isHtml: true
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.ggl-tooltip {
  border: 1px solid #E0E0E0;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica;
  font-size: 10pt;
  padding: 8px 8px 8px 8px;
}

.ggl-tooltip div {
  padding: 4px 4px 4px 4px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart_div"></div>
```

Note: there is a bug when using data views with column properties.
the column properties do not come through to the chart when drawn.
so we must convert the view back to a data table, before drawing.
(see above snippet)

```
view.toDataTable()
```

Comment: Awesome! thank you for reply; do you know how I could make "Days" text to be non-bold as well?